# ADW Launcher (CM7/Desire GSM) old icons keep reappearing/overlapping icons

Tags: cyanogenmod, home-screen-shortcuts

I have an HTC Desire (GSM) running CM7.1 and I am having issues with the ADW desktop:

Icons that I have previously deleted reappear on next boot - sometimes even over or under other icons. If I sort things out and backup the settings and desktop config, reboot and then restore the settings/config this does not cure the problem.

If I add a new app, its icon will appear where put after a reboot, but it's as if a subset of old icons have been remembered somewhere or a config file has become read only. I have tried manually deleting the backup files from the SD card but this doesn't help.

Any ideas?